# After an option skyrockets in price and IV, when will IV decay and drop?

Tags: options, implied-volatility

Consider LEAPS on stocks on BNTX, GME, MRNA, TSLA or ETFs like XSD, SOXX. They've all rocketed in price, and their IV too. Once their IV drops, I'm thinking of buying them. I've been following some of these LEAPS for the past year, and I DO SEE their IV dropping six months after a spike.

How can I estimate or predict when their IV will drop?  Is there some formula from quantitative finance? But I unschooled at math. Haven't done or used any calculus since I was 18!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to predict the future accurately. You could look at previous "spikes" in IV and see how long they lasted, but there's no fundamental formula that would tell you exactly (or even approximately) when future events will occur.

One could also argue that if you *could* predict when the price would drop, then you (and everyone else) would sell before the price drop, causing the price to drop before it was predicted to drop, creating a paradox (or perhaps a self-fulfilling prophesy).

Answer (score 1):

IV is a function of traders' interest in the options.  If there is excess buying volume, IV increases.  If there is excess selling volume, IV decreases.

Sometimes, you can guesstimate how much IV will drop after quarterly earnings announcements but at best, it's still an approximation.  In most other instances, it's impossible to know when and how much IV will rise or fall.

And FWIW, the IV of the stocks that you listed have not rocketed.  Many are near their   low for the past year.